# Oracle Managed Data Reader Returning DBNull for One Database Table

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle-manageddataaccess

Issue:

I am using the Oracle managed data access client to connect to an Oracle eBS database.  When selecting a value from one table I get a result; when changing the table I get a null value.

Background:

In my SQLDeveloper client I can connect to the database and run the following queries:

```sql
SELECT MSIB.SEGMENT1 
FROM APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B MSIB 
WHERE MSIB.ORGANIZATION_ID = 255 AND MSIB.SEGMENT1 = '03F.211';
-- 1 ROW RETURNED - VALUE OF 03F.211

SELECT MC.SEGMENT1 
FROM APPS.MTL_CATEGORIES_VL MC 
WHERE MC.SEGMENT1 = 'A0042I';
-- 1 ROW RETURNED - VALUE OF A0042I
```

Then, in C#, I'm connecting to the database with exactly the same credentials (so it should not be a database permissions issue).

Running this code I get a message box returning what I would expect:  03F.211

```
 OracleConnection oradbcon = new OracleConnection(strOracleConString);
 oradbcon.Open();
 strQuery = "SELECT MSIB.SEGMENT1 FROM APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B MSIB WHERE MSIB.ORGANIZATION_ID = 255 AND MSIB.SEGMENT1 = " + ":ITEM_CODE";
 // strQuery = "SELECT MC.SEGMENT1 FROM APPS.MTL_CATEGORIES_VL MC WHERE MC.SEGMENT1 = " + ":ITEM_CODE";
 OracleCommand oradbcmd = new OracleCommand(strQuery, oradbcon);
 oradbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 OracleParameter p_item_code = new OracleParameter();
 p_item_code.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
 p_item_code.Value = "03F.211";
 // p_item_code.Value = "A0042I";
 oradbcmd.Parameters.Add(p_item_code);
 OracleDataReader oradbdr = oradbcmd.ExecuteReader();
 oradbdr.Read();
 strProductMinor = oradbdr.GetString(0).ToString();
 MessageBox.Show(strProductMinor);
```

But running the code with those commented lines switched I get an error indicating a database null:

```
OracleConnection oradbcon = new OracleConnection(strOracleConString);
oradbcon.Open();
// strQuery = "SELECT MSIB.SEGMENT1 FROM APPS.MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B MSIB WHERE MSIB.ORGANIZATION_ID = 255 AND MSIB.SEGMENT1 = " + ":ITEM_CODE";
strQuery = "SELECT MC.SEGMENT1 FROM APPS.MTL_CATEGORIES_VL MC WHERE MC.SEGMENT1 = " + ":ITEM_CODE";
OracleCommand oradbcmd = new OracleCommand(strQuery, oradbcon);
oradbcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleParameter p_item_code = new OracleParameter();
p_item_code.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Varchar2;
// p_item_code.Value = "03F.211";
p_item_code.Value = "A0042I";
oradbcmd.Parameters.Add(p_item_code);
OracleDataReader oradbdr = oradbcmd.ExecuteReader();
oradbdr.Read();
strProductMinor = oradbdr.GetString(0).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(strProductMinor);
```

> [image: DbNull Error]

What would cause one query to return results but the other to not?

(Finally - forgive my ignorance of C# if anything above is ugly.  Years of Oracle experience - first C# program ever...  :)  )

Comment: Did you try to run the query with hardcoded values instead of parameters? Did that return the correct values? I never connected to oracle using c# so I'm not sure about the parameterized query syntax. May be some value binding issue. But I suppose, you should somehow tell your oracle parameter its name.

Comment: Thanks @derpirscher - I did do that.  Helpful, but I figured it out...

Comment: I figured out what my own issue is.  


APPS.MTL_CATEGORIES_VL is a view in Oracle.  In that view it's looking at another view:  MTL_CATEGORIES_TL  


MTL_CATEGORIES_TL is a "translated language" view - meaning that it will return the results for the language that your Oracle session is connected as.  


SQL Developer is declaring that context.  
The .NET connector isn't doing that.  I have to figure out how to do that or go back to the base tables...

Comment: Try these: 1-Just set your thread.currentCulture to the language that matches your DB before the call; 2- play with this `OracleGlobalization info = conn.GetSessionInfo();...conn.SetSessionInfo(info)`

Answer (score -1):

The issue is language.

APPS.MTL_CATEGORIES_VL is a view that has another view in it's definition:
MTL_CATEGORIES_TL

The views ending in TL are "translated language" meaning they only return results for the language of your database session.

SQL Developer is declaring a default language when I connect.
.NET client is not.

I either need to figure out how to declare a language or re-write my queries to use base tables that don't have language.

Edit:  There was a complaint that this wasn't an actual answer, but an explanation.

Here is the actual code that is the answer:

```
    try // Open Connection
    {
        oradbcon = new OracleConnection(yourConnectionStringHere);
        oradbcon.Open();
        OracleGlobalization orainfo = oradbcon.GetSessionInfo();
        orainfo.Language = "AMERICAN"; // Explicitly Set Language
        oradbcon.SetSessionInfo(orainfo);
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer how to fix it, but rather an explanation of what is wrong. You should post answers only when you **fix** the issue. And this explanation, you can add to your original question.